# Find the number of such $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of natural numbers $n$ for which $n^2-9$ divides $6n^2$.

Seems to me that $n=6$ is the only solution. I wrote a simple code to verify it. Can anyone help me justify why this is the case.

Comment: $\frac{6k}{k-9}=6+\frac{54}{k-9}$ which leaves you with not too many options.

Comment: You can see after the first few values it ranges between $7$ and $6$, and slowly converges to $6$ but using
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{6x^2}{(x+3)(x-3)} = 6$$ see that it can't be an integer for any other value, hence nothing other than $n=6$

Comment: Note that $n=0$ also satisfies the divisbility condition. Whether that counts towards the solutions depends on your convention of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$n^2 - 9 \mid 6n^2 \Longleftrightarrow n^2 - 9 \mid 6n^2 + k(n^2 - 9) $$
for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Setting $k = -6$ gives
$$n^2 - 9 \mid 54$$
Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, this also means $n^2 - 9 \le 54$ and thus
$$1 \le n \le 7$$
Checking all possible values, we only get $n = 6$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs). This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).